# Rescue mode (rescue.target) and Emergency mode (emergency.target) descriptions

Tags: systemd, runlevel

I can't find descriptions of Rescue mode(rescue.target) and Emergency mode(emergency.target) where it would be stated what's started and what's not in each mode.

Some info I find on the web is contradicting each other. Can someone point me to the good source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This info seems to be fully applicable:
https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Based on the text, I take emergency mode to be "a root shell", period; nothing else initialized.

Rescue mode on the other hand has tools to help you get started handling the computer in a reasonable manner - still as root though.

I generally use method 2 (i.e. via the grub menus), actually doing a fsck and then network activation via the final level menu, before dropping to a root shell.
By then, at that root prompt, you have "normal" possibilities to run e.g. `apt` and all that: *e.g. having a display driver problem; remove current driver, find anew one and install it (or reinstall the same).*